# implement android:button="@drawable/checkbox" programmatically

Tags: android, checkbox, android-widget, android-button

I am trying to create custom Check Box  button image. After some research, I came across this code sample:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkFav" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp" android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true"/>
```

My query is how to actually implement android:button in code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[setButtonDrawable(Drawable d)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setButtonDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) is the way to go for. Make sure it is state-list drawable to respond to user interaction.

Step By step instruction

1. Have at least 2 images. (one for checked state and another for normal state)
2. Create xml drawable. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList
3. Use setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.your_xml_drawable).

**Notes-- there are many ways to achieve. This is just one simple way to do it.

Comment: Thanks PH7..however, I believe setButtonDrawable() corresponds with android:drawable="@drawable/image.. Could you please let me know of any other ways to achieve this??

Comment: Have you tried? CheckBox inherit this method from Compound button. If you haven't, give it a try and let me know.

Comment: what about null button? We can use android:button="@null" but I cannot use setButtonDrawable(null). how can we do that?

Comment: setButtonDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent)) should do the trick.

Comment: How about get? any chance of getting the button (e.g for animations)